# Square text problem looking to loop solution

Tags: javascript

So I was tasked to take a string as an input and scramble it into a square code, i.e "If man was meant to stay on the ground god would have given us roots" returns imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau, where each letter in the new string comes from sorting the string into a column and the string is the vertical column of the square. i.e:
    ifmanwas
    meanttos
    tayonthe
    groundgo
    dwouldha
    vegivenu
    sroots

I have a solution but it is clunky and if the square if bigger than 8 x 8 my solution breaks down. Looking to simplify just don't have the logic for it yet.

My intuition tells me there is a way I can loop this but I just can't see the method.

```
    const squareCode = function(message) {

    let newString = ""
      let string = message.replace(/ /g, "");

    let root =Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(string.length))

    root = Math.round(root)

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if (i % root == 0 || i == 0){

        newString += string[i] 

      }  
      } newString += " "
      for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if (i % root == 1  ){
        newString += string[i]
      } 
    } newString += " "
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i ++){
     if (i % root ==2){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    }  newString += " "
    for (let i =0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if ( i % root ==3){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    } newString += " "
    for (let i =0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if ( i % root ==4){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    } newString += " "
    for (let i =0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if ( i % root ==5){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    } newString += " "
    for (let i =0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if ( i % root ==6){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    } newString += " "
    for (let i =0; i < string.length; i ++){
      if ( i % root ==7){
        newString += string[i]
      }
    } newString += " "

    return newString
    }

    console.log(squareCode("chill out"));
    console.log(squareCode("feed the dog"));
    console.log(squareCode("have a nice day"));
    console.log(squareCode("if man was meant to stay on the ground god would have given us roots"));
     //my output
     //clu hlt io  
     //fto ehg ee dd
     //hae and via ecy
     //imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau
```

I'm getting what I want i'd just prefer to do it in less than 50 lines of code.

Comment: could you write the desired output?

Comment: @StepUp - it's in the question

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it using Array#reduce

```js
const squareCode = message => {
    let string = message.replace(/\s+/g, "").split('');
    let length = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(string.length));
    return string.reduce((acc, l, i) => (acc[i%length] += l, acc), new Array(length).fill('')).join(' ');
};

console.log(squareCode("chill out"));
console.log(squareCode("feed the dog"));
console.log(squareCode("have a nice day"));
console.log(squareCode("if man was meant to stay on the ground god would have given us roots"));
```

If the quest is to do it in as few lines of code as possible, regardless of readability

```js
const squareCode = m => m.replace(/\s+/g, "").split('').reduce((a, l, i) => (a[i%Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(m.replace(/\s+/g, "").split('').length))] += l, a), new Array(Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(m.replace(/\s+/g, "").split('').length))).fill('')).join(' ');

console.log(squareCode("chill out"));
console.log(squareCode("feed the dog"));
console.log(squareCode("have a nice day"));
console.log(squareCode("if man was meant to stay on the ground god would have given us roots"));
```